# Elasticsearch count hits for each document match of condition

Tags: elasticsearch

I getting familiar with elastic search queries and am trying to find a solution for the following scenario:

```
  const { hits: { total: count } } = await esClient.search({
    index,
    body: {
      size: 0,
      track_total_hits: true,
      query: {
        constant_score: {
          filter: {
            bool: {
              should: [
                condition1,  
                condition2
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

If there is a document matching condition1 AND condition2, it should be counted as 2 hits.

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks!

Important: This is with ES version 6.8

Comment: did you get a chance to try my answer ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't get the chance to try it – the requirement changed in the meantime.

Comment: Ahh, got it, I just wanted to follow up if it works for you or you have some follow-up queries, anyway if you get a chance you can try it to close the topic

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the Elasticsearch, you can have n number of conditions in your Elasticsearch query but ultimately hit count represent the documents **that matches all the conditions in Elasticsearch query**.

What you can do is after getting the hits from Elasticsearch, if you have lets suppose 4 conditions and you have 100 hits from Elasticsearch, it simply means you have 400 hits according to your use-case.